# Disable the Save As Button in Word 2010

Tags: c#, interop, word-2010

I have the following code that should disable the Save As button in Word 2010. The method below is being called in the `Document_Startup` event:

```
private void DisableSaveAsButton()
{
    Object MenuBar = 40;
    Object FileMenu = 1;
    Object SaveAsButton = 5;
    var saveAsBtn = this.ThisApplication.CommandBars[MenuBar].Controls[FileMenu].accChild[SaveAsButton] as CommandBarButton;
    saveAsBtn.Enabled = false;
}
```

I am expecting the Save as Button to be grayed out, but it isn't and it still functions. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: does this help http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee815851.aspx

Answer (score 4):

I figured it out.  I just had to add a Ribbon XML item to the project with the following info below.  I also needed to disable a few other buttons:

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
     <customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/01/customui" 
        onLoad="OnLoad" > 
        <commands> 
          <command idMso="FileSaveAs" enabled="false" />
          <command idMso="FileNewDefault" enabled="false"/>
          <command idMso="FileOpen" enabled="false"/>
          <command idMso="FileOpenRecentFile" enabled="false"/>
        </commands> 
     </customUI>
```

Comment: Where did you have to add this XML?

Comment: Also, if you want the list of available `idMso` values, see these pages: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=3582 (Office 2007), http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=1574 (Office 2010), or http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36798 (Office 2013)

Comment: I am facing same kind of problem in a windows forms app. Can you plz let me know where exactly I can add this xml file and where to refer it?

Comment: In case anyone drops by needing this, the default Ribbon is Ribbon1.xml. I found mine by searching for: <commands>